# Can't fetch git source through Podfile

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to include a git source in my Podfile :

```
pod 'RBStoryboardLink', :git => 'https://github.com/sedonaFR/RBStoryboardLink.git'
```

but it gives me the following error :

> [!] The `RBStoryboardLink` pod failed to validate due to 1 error.
>
> - ERROR | source: The commit of a Git source cannot be `HEAD`.
> - WARN  | source: Git sources should specify a tag.

I tried to specify the branch and the commit SHA-1 but it did not work either. I do not own this repo and it doesn't have any tag on it. Does that mean I can't include it using a Podfile ?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use `https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink.git`? Why are you using sedonaFR's git? Is there some different code? If you are facing issue, try reporting issue in that repo itself.

Comment: Good point, I did not realize that I was using some sort of cloned repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out and it will download the  - RBStoryboardLink (0.1.4) version

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target ‘<TargetName>’ do

pod 'RBStoryboardLink'

end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. I also had to set "Build Active Architecture Only" flag to NO in the Build Settings of my Pods projects, otherwise the header files were not found.